# How to send multiple variables to a php file via android?

Tags: php, android, json

Hello I have problem with my Android Application. I try to Parse a JSON response from a php file i have with variables in my SQL Query. I get the right response in my Browser but i get an Error in my android application That it can not be parsed. If i run it without variables i don't get any error in my Android but i can not perform the search i want. Down i present you the php and Android files.

get_all_products.php

```
<?php

//Used to compress Errors about old version of PHP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);// To be changed
//Used to compress Errors about old version of PHP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

/*
 * The following code will list all the MuseumItems
 */

//Array for JSON responce
$responce = array();

//Include db connect class
require_once __DIR__.'/db_connect.php';

//Connection to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

//Variable for search strings
//$item_name = $_POST['ItemName'];
//$item_type = $_POST['ItemType'];
//$item_historic_period = $_POST['ItemHistoricPeriod'];

//Get all Items from museumItem table
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM museumItems WHERE "
  //      . "ItemName = '{$_POST['itemName']}'"
    //    . "OR ItemType = '{$_GET['itemType']}' "
      //  . "OR ItemHistoricPeriod = '{$_GET['itemHistoricPeriod']}' ")
        //or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM museumItems";

$itemName = $_GET["ItemName"];
$itemType = $_GET["ItemType"];
$itemHistoricPeriod = $_GET["ItemHistoricPeriod"];

$wherestr = "";
if ($itemName)
{
    if (strlen($wherestr) > 0) $wherestr .= " OR ";
    $wherestr .= "ItemName LIKE '%{$itemName}%'";
}
if ($itemType)
{
    if (strlen($wherestr) > 0) $wherestr .= " OR ";
        $wherestr .= "ItemType LIKE '%{$itemType}%'";
}
if ($itemHistoricPeriod)
{
    if (strlen($wherestr) > 0) $wherestr .= " OR ";
        $wherestr .= "ItemHistoricPeriod LIKE '%{$itemHistoricPeriod}%'";
}

//var_dump($wherestr);

    if (strlen($wherestr) > 0){
        $query .= " WHERE {$wherestr}";
    }
    //var_dump($query);

    //3. EXECUTE QUERY
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;

    //echo $query;

//Check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    //Looping trough all results
    //museumItems node
    $responce["museumItems"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        //Temp user array
        $museum_item = array();

        $museum_item["id"] = $row["ID"];
        $museum_item["itemName"] = $row["ItemName"];
        $museum_item["artistName"] = $row["ArtistName"];
        $museum_item["itemLocation"] = $row["ItemLocation"];
        $museum_item["itemHistoricPeriod"] = $row["ItemHistoricPeriod"];
        $museum_item["itemType"] = $row["ItemType"];
        $museum_item["itemDescription"] = $row["ItemDescription"];
        $museum_item["itemURL"] = $row["ItemURL"];
        $museum_item["itemImage"] = $row["ItemImage"];

            //Push single item into final responce array
            array_push($responce["museumItems"], $museum_item);
    }
    //Success
    $responce["success"] = 1;

    //Echoing JSON responce
    echo json_encode($responce);

}else
{
    //No items found
    $responce["success"] = 0;
    $responce["message"] = "No products found";

    //Echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($responce);
}

?>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    static String nameSearchCriteria;
    static String typeSearchCriteria;
    static String historicalPeriodCriteria;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void goToSearchActivity(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplaySearchResultsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        EditText nameSearchCriteriaEditText =
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchActivityQueryByNameEditText);
        nameSearchCriteria = nameSearchCriteriaEditText.getText().toString();

        EditText typeSearchCriteriaEditText =
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchActivityQueryByTypeEditText);
        typeSearchCriteria = typeSearchCriteriaEditText.getText().toString();

        EditText historicalPeriodCriteriaEditText =
                (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchActivityQueryByHistoricPeriodEditText);
        historicalPeriodCriteria = historicalPeriodCriteriaEditText.getText().toString();

        System.out.printf(nameSearchCriteria);
    }
}
```

DisplaySearchResultActivity.java

```
package com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class DisplaySearchResultsActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> museumItemsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_search_results = "http://10.0.3.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";


    // JSON Node names
    static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEMS = "museumItems";
    static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID = "id";
    static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME = "itemName";
    static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST = "artistName";
    static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION = "itemLocation";
    static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD = "itemHistoricalPeriod";
    static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_TYPE = "itemType";
    static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_DESCRIPTION = "itemDescription";
    static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ITEM_URL = "itemURL";
    static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE = "itemImage";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray museumItems = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_search_resaults);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        museumItemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        //OnItemClick implementation

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv = getListView();

        // ListView on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String singleItemName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.museum_item_name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String singleItemArtist = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.museum_item_artist))
                        .getText().toString();
                String singleItemLocation = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.museum_item_location))
                        .getText().toString();
                String singleItemHistoricPeriod = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.museum_item_historic_period))
                        .getText().toString();
                //String singleItemType = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.museum_item_historic_period))
                //        .getText().toString();
                String singleItemDescription = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.single_item_description))
                        .getText().toString();
                String singleItemURL = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.museum_item_URL))
                        .getText().toString();
                String singleItemImage = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.single_item_image_link))
                        .getText().toString();


                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME, singleItemName);
                in.putExtra(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST, singleItemArtist);
                in.putExtra(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION, singleItemLocation);
                in.putExtra(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD, singleItemHistoricPeriod);
                //in.putExtra(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_TYPE, singleItemType);
                in.putExtra(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, singleItemDescription);
                in.putExtra(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ITEM_URL, singleItemURL);
                in.putExtra(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE, singleItemImage);

                startActivity(in);
            }

        });

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Museum Items. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_search_results, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON response
            Log.d("All Museum Items: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    museumItems = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEMS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < museumItems.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = museumItems.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String item_id = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID);
                        String item_name = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME);
                        String item_artist = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST);
                        String item_historic_period = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD);
                        String item_location = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION);
                        String item_type = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_TYPE);
                        String item_description = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_DESCRIPTION);
                        String item_URL = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ITEM_URL);
                        String list_image = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID, item_id);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME, item_name);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST, item_artist);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD, item_historic_period);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION, item_location);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_TYPE, item_type);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, item_description);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ITEM_URL,item_URL);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE, list_image);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        museumItemsList.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                    ListAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.this, museumItemsList);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

**URL**

```
http://localhost/android_connect/get_all_products.php?ItemName=Mona%20Lisa&ItemHistoricPeriod=1889&ItemType=Painting
```

**And my JSON response:**

```
{"museumItems":[{"id":"1","itemName":"Mona Lisa","artistName":"Leonardo da Vinci","itemLocation":"Louvre Museum, Paris","itemHistoricPeriod":"1503 - 1506","itemType":"Painting","itemDescription":"The Mona Lisa (Monna Lisa or La Gioconda in Italian; La Joconde in French) is a half-length portrait of a woman by the Italian artist Leonardo da Vinci, which has been acclaimed as \"the best known, the most visited, the most written about, the most sung about, the most parodied work of art in the world\"","itemURL":"http:\/\/www.louvre.fr\/en\/oeuvre-notices\/mona-lisa-%E2%80%93-portrait-lisa-gherardini-wife-francesco-del-giocondo","itemImage":"http:\/\/10.0.3.2\/image_folder\/mona_lisa.png"},{"id":"2","itemName":"The Scream","artistName":"Edvard Munch","itemLocation":"National Gallery, Oslo, Norway","itemHistoricPeriod":"1893","itemType":"Painting","itemDescription":"The Scream (Norwegian: Skrik) is the popular name given to each of four versions of a composition, created as both paintings and pastels, by the Expressionist artist Edvard Munch between 1893 and 1910. Der Schrei der Natur (The Scream of Nature) is the title Munch gave to these works, all of which show a figure with an agonized expression against a landscape with a tumultuous orange sky. Arthur Lubow has described The Scream as \"an icon of modern art, a Mona Lisa for our time.\"","itemURL":"http:\/\/www.edvardmunch.org\/the-scream.jsp","itemImage":"http:\/\/10.0.3.2\/image_folder\/The_Scream.png"},{"id":"3","itemName":"The Starry Night","artistName":"Vincent van Gogh","itemLocation":"Museum of Modern Art, New York City","itemHistoricPeriod":"1889","itemType":"Painting","itemDescription":"The Starry Night is an oil on canvas by the Dutch post-impressionist painter Vincent van Gogh. Painted in June, 1889, it depicts the view from the east-facing window of his asylum room at Saint-R?my-de-Provence, just before sunrise, with the addition of an idealized village.It has been in the permanent collection of the Museum of Modern Art in New York City since 1941, acquired through the Lillie P. Bliss Bequest. It is regarded as among Van Gogh's finest works, and one of the most recognized monuments in the history of Western culture.","itemURL":"http:\/\/www.moma.org\/collection\/object.php?object_id=79802","itemImage":"http:\/\/10.0.3.2\/image_folder\/Night.png"},{"id":"4","itemName":"The Last Supper","artistName":"Leonardo da Vinci","itemLocation":"Santa Maria delle Grazie, Milan","itemHistoricPeriod":"1494 - 1499","itemType":"Painting","itemDescription":"The Last Supper (Italian: Il Cenacolo or L'Ultima Cena) is a late 15th-century mural painting by Leonardo da Vinci in the refectory of the Convent of Santa Maria delle Grazie, Milan. It is one of the world's most famous paintings, and one of the most studied, scrutinized, and satirized.","itemURL":"http:\/\/milan.arounder.com\/en\/churches\/santa-maria-delle-grazie-church","itemImage":"http:\/\/10.0.3.2\/image_folder\/The_Last_Supper.png"},{"id":"5","itemName":"Guernica","artistName":"Pablo Picasso","itemLocation":"Museo Reina Sofia, Madrid, Spain","itemHistoricPeriod":"1937","itemType":"Painting","itemDescription":"Guernica is a mural-sized oil painting on canvas by Spanish artist Pablo Picasso completed by June 1937.The painting, which uses a palette of gray, black, and white, is known as one of the most moving and powerful anti-war paintings in history.Standing at 3.49 metres (11 ft 5 in) tall and 7.76 metres (25 ft 6 in) wide, the large mural shows the suffering of people, animals, and buildings wrenched by violence and chaos.","itemURL":"http:\/\/www.pablopicasso.org\/guernica.jsp","itemImage":"http:\/\/10.0.3.2\/image_folder\/Guernica.png"}],"success":1}
```

**Log Cat Error:**

```
05-25 07:03:18.036    1249-1264/com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-25 07:03:18.052    1249-1264/com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication.DisplaySearchResultsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.java:146)
            at com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication.DisplaySearchResultsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.java:121)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-25 07:03:18.648    1249-1249/com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication.DisplaySearchResultsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5354cb68 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,192} that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication.DisplaySearchResultsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5354cb68 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,192} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
            at com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication.DisplaySearchResultsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.java:133)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
            at com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication.DisplaySearchResultsActivity.onCreate(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.java:64)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the json reponse

Comment: First tell me, are you able to get the response?

Comment: Edited my code above

Comment: can you post your logcat what error you get

Comment: What is on line 146 ? DisplaySearchResultsActivity.java:146

Comment: Log.d("All Museum Items: ", json.toString());

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this that you are using itemHistoricalPeriod where as in response it is itemHistoricPeriod

Comment: i think it is the problem, i haven't test run the code but reviewed i find that mistake let me know if it helps

Comment: that is not a problem

Comment: that is one of the problem too, let me see your log cat see if i can figure it out

Comment: see DisplaySearchResultsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.java:146), here some object is null.   Log.d("All Museum Items: ", json.toString()); i think json is null

Comment: and in some case i think there is some html coming in your response like "<br " that is why it is stating json parsing error

Comment: yes but why is it null when i try to pass variables from android via php?

Comment: what i can tell you by logs is that in you that particular request the web service result have some improper html tag, here you log cat says Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject so there is a line break tag that is why it fails to convert the repose to jsonobject and thus you json object resulted null. See your webservice and the reponse string if it send html or improper json in any case.

Comment: hope it helps, happy coding :)

Comment: post your JSONParser class, or you can see it yourself in JSONParser the methord you are calling  jParser.makeHttpRequest in that method somewhere you should be getting the response string. Or use plugin post man and on that make the service call and see the response.